# Question on the proof of transpose of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am in an honors linear algebra course and I am confused on a small step in proving a theorem.

I am using Friedberg's linear algebra.

Here is a link to the theorem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXYkD.jpg

I understand the T($x_i$) is being expressed in terms of the basis vectors of W. What I do not get is why the coefficients of each $y_k$ are $A_{(k,i)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition of $[T]_\gamma^\beta$. You first compute the transformation of the basis $\beta$ (i.e. $T(x_i)$ for all $i$). Then, you find the coordinate column vectors for these $T(x_i)$ in terms of $\gamma$, i.e. compute the unique coefficients $a_{1i}, \ldots, a_{mi}$ such that
$$T(x_i) = a_{1i} y_1 + \ldots a_{mi} y_m,$$
and stick these coordinates into a column vector:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{1i} \\ a_{2i} \\ \vdots \\ a_{mi}\end{pmatrix}.$$
This column vector forms the $i$th column of $[T]_\gamma^\beta$. So, we get,
$$[T]_\gamma^\beta = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \ldots & a_{mn}\end{pmatrix}.$$
So, as you can see, $A_{ki}$, the entry in the $k$th row and $i$th column, is the $k$th coordinate (i.e. the coefficient of $y_k$) of $T(x_i)$.